# LocationManager sending null

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am using Google Map V2 and i trying to get the current location.But it is always returning null .

**Code**

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
```

Every time i am getting `location` null .My GPS is working fine in my device what can the issue please help me.

Comment: Using GPS to find location takes more time so you receive null,if you use network provider you get it in a second

Comment: Open native map app and then open your app it gives location,this is the problem with GPS provider, Better you can try Fused Location Provider to avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

Per the [getLastKnownLocation documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29):

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

as you are using `getBestProvider(criteria, false)` you are saying you allow providers that are not enabled (that's what `false` means) - switch it to `true` if you only want to look at enabled providers (which will assure that getLastKnownLocation does not return null).

Note that the `getLastKnownLocation` could be very out of date and you may still want to look for location updates if you need to get a recent location.

Answer (score 0):

There are different approach. First of all be sure that you have all required permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

If you only want an approximate location you can get the lastlocation (GPS or NETWORK)

```
if(_locationManager != null)
{
    if(_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) != null)
        return new Location(_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),true);

    else if(_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER) != null)
        return new Location(_locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER),true);      
}
```